# Hibernate apache lucene based full text search with one static filter

Tags: hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

**my goal is search only in  active items**
here is my code snippet:

```
 FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
            Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.getEntityManager());

    QueryBuilder queryBuilder =
        fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder()
        .forEntity(Myclass.class)
        .get();

    BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> booleanJunction = queryBuilder.bool();

    for(String token : tokens){
        booleanJunction.should( queryBuilder.keyword()
            .wildcard()
            .onFields("field1", "field2", "field3")
            .matching(token + "*")
            .createQuery());
    }

    FullTextQuery jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(booleanJunction.createQuery(), MyClass.class);
```

I want to filter with field4 which is Object,Enum, 
I have try this:

```
booleanJunction.must( queryBuilder.keyword()
            .wildcard()
            .onField("field4")
            .matching(Status.ACTIVE)
            .createQuery());
```

Status object is Enum.

in this case if the upper should not find anything result is all active items , it happens because it is bool query..

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a query someting like:

```
+(token1* token2* token3*) +field4:active
```

To build that, you don't want to add the field4:active part to the same boolean query as the set of tokens, you'll want to create a parent boolean query to add the set of token queries as a required (must) query.  Something like:

```
BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> parentJunction = queryBuilder.bool();
parentJunction.must(booleanJunction.createQuery());
parentJunction.must(field4activeQuery);
```